# Firebase: ¿Como puedo hacer un perfil para cada usuario?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

mi pregunta es como puedo crear un sistema que me permita que cada usuario que se registre, tenga cada uno un perfil, es decir que si tengo x usuario que se registra con su email, contraseña (firebase auth) y tambien escribe en un input su nombre y apellido, ***yo pueda hacer un perfil para cada uno*** *(Algo asi como las redes sociales)*

Avance bastante desde que hice la pregunta de arriba (Jamás la publique porque leyendo la documentación pude avanzar), pero ahora me estanque varios días con algo que no puedo realizar,

Como explica ***el primer párrafo***, tengo un registro con *firebase auth*

```
    const auth = getAuth()
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then ((userCredential) => {
    console.log('Registrado') //Mensaje de registro exitoso
    const user = userCredential.user  //Guarda el usuario
    console.log(user.uid)
    console.log(user.email)
    backend(user);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code
    const errorMessage = error.message
    console.log('error: ' + errorMessage + 'Error code  ' + errorCode)
    
    let errorHTML = document.getElementById('error');
    errorHTML.innerHTML = errorMessage;

  })
```

Y luego cuando llamo a la funcion backend, **envia a firestore lo siguiente:**

```
    const backend = async (user) => {
  const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    username: username,
    userID: user.uid, 
  });
  console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
}
```

Y una vez enviado todo eso (Lo cual funciona bien), me gustaría que se redireccione a una pantalla donde s**egún el nombre que puso, aparezca en pantalla el mismo** *(en otro archivo .jsx)*

**Según lo que leí,** **era muy importante guardar el uid de cada registro,** así que lo envió también a firestore, pero me estanque, agradezco enormemente su ayuda.

Saludos

Comment: En realidad, no necesitarías hacer un perfil para cada usuario, ya que firebase auth hace una base de datos de usuarios dentro de la sección de Users, si no es eso lo que buscas, ¿a qué te refieres con tener un perfil?

Comment: Bueno cuando te creas una cuenta en instagram, por ejemplo, tenes tu perfil con tu nombre y apellido, hasta un username, yo todo eso lo paso por parametro en firestore, pero no se como hacer para mostrarlo segun que cuenta esta logeada, yo me imaginaba que era algo de manipular el user.uid de firebase auth, pero no se me ocurre ninguna forma de llevarlo a cabo

Comment: Bueno, lo que tengo entendido acerca del propósito de Firebase Auth es proporcionar un rápido y seguro método de autenticación interno (firebase) o con redes sociales (facebook,twitter,apple, google,yahoo,etc), su propósito no es manipular perfiles ni roles, si tu propósito es ese, yo te sugeriría que implementaras esa lógica de manera interna de tu lado en una base de datos independiente.

Comment: Pero Fernando. Se supone que se podría hacer utilizando firestore como explique en la publicación, porque tendría que cambiar de base de datos?

Comment: Sí, @Hatori Hanso Estás en lo correcto, el gestor de base de datos que sea el que tú gustes, pero manéjalo así, aparte :)

Comment: @FernandoTorres creo que no estás del todo en lo correcto, ya que confirebase no solo se puede hacer el proceso de autenticación. Si miras bien existe lo que es Firebase Real Data Time y CloudFirestore, lo que se puede hacer es definir una BD pero no relacional haciendo uso de cualquiera de los dos que mencioné, el problema que va a haber es que entre mas cosas se delegen al firebase, mayor va a ser el costo en consumos por usuario y al aumentar esa cantidad de usuarios, va a requerir de algún plan de pago con firebase para poder seguir sin problemas creciendo

Comment: hola @jGomez excelente comentario :) esa fue parte de mi sugerencia, tal vez se  mal entendió lo que dije pero, al final, mi sugerencia era llevar ese control en cualquier tipo de bd externa, ya sea la de firebase o la que a él le convenciera más :) saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una vez que el usuario ya esta creado en autenticacion y en la coleccion de usuarios debes crear un estado que guarde al usuario al momento de hacer login,y asi puedes acceder al usuario autenticado en el estado user y STATUS="LOAGEADO",aqui lo importante es hacer uso de un Contexto de seguridad que encapsule toda la APP

EN TU APP.JSX debes encapsularlo en un contexto global,asi podras acceder al usuario todo el tiempo

```
<SecurityContextProvider>
          <AppRender />
        </SecurityContextProvider>
```

Y en ese contexto haces la autenticacion y declaras el estado del usuario

```
   let [user, setuser] = React.useState({
  id: "",
  first_name: "",
  last_name: "",
  status: "NO_LOGGIN",
});

const loginFirebase = async ({ email, password }) => {
  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((data) => {
      //aqui busca el usuario segun el id de la autenticación al obtenerlo seteaas el usuario en estado LOGEADO
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (err.code == "auth/user-not-found") {
        registerFirebase({ email, password });
      }
    });
};
```

Comment: status: "NO_LOGGIN" esto no tiene ninguna utilidad...

Comment: claro que si,ese campo status es el que debe estar el el useEffect en el momento que cambie a NO_LOGGIN o la constantre que definas cierras sesión

Comment: Pero eso lo controla Firebase

Comment: Pero no react,si quieres propagar en toda la aplicación debes saberlo con un estado,o si no en cada componente debes preguntar a firebase si estoy auth

Comment: Solo con suscribirte al evento de login basta para saber si cambio o no de usuario, es un useEffect con onAuthStateChange. No es necesario nada mas...

Comment: Como estas, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero sigo sin entender varias cosas, por ejemplo, <SecurityContextProvider> y <AppRender> No se donde declararlos, al ponerlos en el app.js me dice que no estan declarados, y lo que es la autentificacion y validacion del usuario, tampoco se donde ponerlo

Comment: Ya has trabajado con contextos? Debes crear un contexto de seguridad y ponerselos a tu componente app